# Simple SELECT query returns no result in Postgres database, depending on user

Tags: sql, postgresql, permissions, row-level-security

I am trying to create a read all user for my database, but it seems the most simplest of queries isn't working properly.

When I try running the query `select * from public.reports limit 5;` it works fine when using the `postgres` user (db owner), returning 5 lines of results. However, it returns no results when using this new user. It throws no errors, it says nothing. It simply returns no results, as if the table was empty.

I created the new user using the following queries:

```
CREATE USER "new_user" WITH PASSWORD 'strong_password';
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE my_database TO "new_user";
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO "new_user";
GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO "new_user";
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public to "new_user";
ALTER USER "new_user" WITH LOGIN;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are [Row Security Policies](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html) in use? A.k.a."Row-Level Security".

Comment: Actually, I think they are being used. How can I enable them for my `new_user`?

Comment: What steps are you following to connect as new_user. Can you share the output of -   select 'Database : ' ||current_database()||', '||'User : '|| user db_details;

Comment: I am trying to connect to my databse through a web service called Metabase. I am connecting by a connection string, ex: `postgres://user:password@db_url:5432/my_db`. The query you asked me to run outputed the name of `my_database` and `new_user`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have row-level security enabled? [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createpolicy.html)

> If row-level security is enabled for a table, but no applicable
>   policies exist, a “default deny” policy is assumed, so that no rows
>   will be visible or updatable.

This would explain that your user cannot see any rows.

The simplest way to bypass RLS *generally* for the new user is with `BYPASSRLS`.

```
CREATE USER new_user WITH BYPASSRLS PASSWORD 'strong_password';
```

Else, you need [`CREATE POLICY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createpolicy.html) to allow things. To allow all read and write operations on table `reports` for our new role:

```
CREATE POLICY foo ON public.reports TO new_user USING (true) WITH CHECK (true);
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm.